# Which open source search engine to choose: sociability, lots of updates, facet search....?

Tags: solr, open-source, elasticsearch

I am doing a project that needs a search engine that supports these key requirements:

1. salable: indexed rows will be in millions and keep growing.
2. real-time updates: there will be constant record inserts and updates. Ideally, the newly inserted or modified records get searchable immediately. There will be deletes, but few.
3. faceted search.
4. relevant results: high on-top search results must be more relevant than later results in a result set.
5. controlled results: search results can be controlled. For example: only return records before a certain date.

I was thinking Solr before, but got concerned because of requirement #2. I am not sure whether Solr can handles #2 beautifully for a very large database.

Any suggestion or pointers about Solr or other open-source search engines.

Thanks in advance!

Regards.

Comment: I use solr for all the things you list except #2.  I know that it handles thousands of updates but I typically batch them in groups of 1000s because #2 is not a requirement for me.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for your input. What could be Solr's behavior when its indexed database of 5 million records gets a batch of 1000 updates? How long could the index rebuilt take? I really want to get some idea. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Looking at "pure scalability" it too narrow here. Sure, Elasticsearch has been built as a distributed engine from the ground up, but look up other important differences: the JSON-based query DSL, rich API for index aliases, Percolator, ...

Comment: @karmi, do you know whether Solr has any effective solution to requirement# 2? I did quite search for it, but did not get anything. Thanks!

Comment: as to SOlr for #2: have a look at Solr NRT (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

Although Solr has Solr NRT (near real time) for your #2, ES is really build from the ground up to provide realtime search capabilities. Also it builds upon Lucene (like Solr) so there's a nice crossover in functionality between Solr, Lucene and ES.

Also scalability was a concern from the ground up for ES, although Solr has recently made some progress in this regard as well. Still, foursquare, github etc rely on ES, so my bet is you're good to go for at least some time to come ;)

Comment: Thanks sooooo much for your information. I am not familiar with ElasticSearch. Do you know whether ElasticSearch meets all the requirements I listed in the original post? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it does. Have a look at the provided url. ES is not yet as well-known as Solr (ES is only a couple of years old), but it's battle hardenend and in production with lots of big companies (like Solr). It provides #1 and #2 out of the box (in constrast to Solr) . All your other points are pretty trivial so are easily satisfied both with ES as well as Solr.